# What does the error "Unable to load metadata for game" means in Google Play Game Service?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-console

A couple of days ago Google announced the Google Play Game Services. Very cool of course, so I started integrating into my game.

I think I did every step correctly to be able to sign in with your Google+ account, but it's not working. The developer console says the game is ready for testing.

I always get the following message in my logcat:

```
05-19 10:20:30.538: E/Volley(27130): [1704] il.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=nl_NL&platformType=ANDROID
05-19 10:20:30.538: E/GameAgent(27130): Unable to retrieve 1P application 123456789012-123abcdefghijklmnop456qrst789uvw from network
05-19 10:20:30.618: E/CheckGameplayAcl(13964): Unable to load metadata for game
```

I have set up two test accounts inside the game service configuration. Both give the same result.

What does the error "Unable to load metadata for game" means? Is there something wrong with my configuration? Or is my ApplicationID not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you app id is incorrect. Try again with 123456789012 (removing -123abcdefghijklmnop456qrst789uvw)